# ffmpeg recoded mp4 files error on mobiles in Video JS

Tags: ffmpeg, video.js, android-ffmpeg

We are converting seriously old .flv files to MP4 with FFMPEG. These are at least 10 years old.
Back then all were rendered with early versions of Adobe Premiere.

On desktop browsers all the files work and stream (...watching them feels like going back a century!)

But when requesting the videos on the same pages on mobile devices (android and ios) Video JS doesn't even show up.
Perhaps the codec is just too old, but I was wondering if there could be another reason when converting them with this line:

```
for i in *.flv; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

If not, is it possible to detect this in Video JS, so we can show an announcement that the video is only visible on desktops?

I hope someone here has this knowledge!

**added on request of [llogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109017/llogan)**

```
ffmpeg version N-78967-gbaec6d8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)   configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build
--extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265   libavutil      55. 19.100 / 55. 19.100   libavcodec     57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100   libavformat    57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101   libavfilter     6. 39.102 / 
6. 39.102   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'a_4293_06.mp4':   Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.28.100   Duration: 00:01:40.10, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 492 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x240, 376 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 123 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Show the complete log from one of the conversions, or show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i notworkingvideo.mp4`. Without it we can only guess as there are too many possible reasons and variables to provide an answer without this information.

Comment: Your ffmpeg is old. You should update it before doing anything else. [Downloading](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) a recent one is easy. Once you do that then add `-movflags +faststart` to your command. You could simply re-mux what you encoded with this option, but since your ffmpeg is so old I recommend re-encoding from the FLV inputs again.

Comment: Superthanks @llogan! I will do that and let you know it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@llogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1109017/llogan)'s comments I can answer this one myself.

First, I upgraded ffmpeg to the latest version, and then did some research on the **-movflags** and **+faststart**.

I found a 2015 article with great info on how to convert .flv to .mp4 (https://addpipe.com/blog/flv-to-mp4/)

So, in order to make the new .mp4 files compatible with mobile devices, you need to add a profile and a level, like this:

in a **batch convert**:

```
for i in *.flv; do ffmpeg -y  -i "$i" -movflags +faststart -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 "${i%.*}.mp4"; done
```

and for a **single file**:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.flv -movflags +faststart -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 filename.mp4
```

And then the terminal shows this line when converting:

> Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the
>   file

That is needed, but the addition of the **-profile** and **-level** actually made the videos work on the mobile devices.

Comment: Must be some really ancient devices to need `-profile:v baseline -level 3.0`. You may be able to use `-profile:v main` instead.

Comment: I am depending on the original coding of the flv. Does that make a difference? The files are over 10 yrs old. And the latest versions of all system and apps on the Oneplus 5 still give errors in some (irregular) cases..
Still, it is all about Video JS here in which things don't show on mobile.

Comment: You didn't show any info on the inputs so I can't comment on them (it was one reason why I asked for the complete log from one of the conversions).

Comment: Sorry for not showing the input on my part. We're only used to using a few commands with ffmpeg that give us results like screen shots from videos - the easy commands. But I did test your suggestion with the '-profile:v main,' and it gave errors on some files, say: on 10% of them. These files are really, really old, so we set the compatibility as low as possible. And it works on all devices as of a few days ago - errors even happened on my One Plus 5 in Chrome. They are gone -except for when using the '-main' addition. Concluding: my answer on your help still stands, so the thanks remains!